# how to getRotationMatrix having only accelerometer sensor in device

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensormanager

I want to get device rotation and i have achieved somehow but the code is not working which device is not present with Magentic sensor,Orientation sensor and Gyroscope sensor. But i have seen some app those are working like [XClinometer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.plaincode.clinometer&hl=en) and [iHandy level free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ihandysoft.carpenter.level&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5paGFuZHlzb2Z0LmNhcnBlbnRlci5sZXZlbCJd) on device .Having device htc Explorer not giving value as not present with these sensor.please tell me how i can achieve this task.
I have use this code but as sensor not available so not getting any value so no rotation matrix as well.

```
  @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            // copy new accelerometer data into accel array and calculate
            // orientation
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, accel, 0, 3);
            calculateAccMagOrientation();
            break;

        case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:
            // process gyro data
            gyroFunction(event);
            break;

        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            // copy new magnetometer data into magnet array
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, magnet, 0, 3);
            break;

        }
```

}

and the method is

```
public void calculateAccMagOrientation() {

         if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accel,
                magnet)) {
            SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, SensorManager.AXIS_X,
                    SensorManager.AXIS_Y, mValuesOrientation);
            SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, mValuesOrientation);

        }else{
            //float[] array = new float[9];
            if(magnet[0]<=0){
                System.out.println("herr.....");
                System.out.println();
            }else{
                System.out.println("null so herr.....");
            }
            /*on htc device it is coming here so i need code here to get angle as only received accelerometer sensor data.
           */
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples you link to only need the tilt angles, not the rotation matrix. It is enough to have accelerometers to get the tilt angles.

The rotation matrix contains more information than the tilt angles and it requires gyroscopes as well.

Comment: for tilt angle what process i need to do.

Comment: is using Math.atan2(y/x) is efficient or some other way..btw i got using this

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Yes, you get the angles by one of the inverse trigonometric functions. You have to give a clear definition of the tilt angles you are interested in and the notations you are using.

Comment: can u suggest me how the app clinometer is drawing bubble as per device movement on UI as i need something similar work to do.actually i hav done using rotation matrix if present but as on htc it is not so please tell me if u know something regarding this.the angle part i did using trignometric func.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: I would use the accelerometer, smooth the values with a [low-pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Algorithmic_implementation) then compute the angles with the corresponding inverse trigonometric function. This is enough to draw that bubble interactively, it will move reasonably and smoothly.

Comment: i hav tried to understand the concept low pass filter but i am unable to implement this.if u have something for low pass filter besides a pseudo code than it can help me a lot.